# No me corre mi HolaMundo?

Tags: java, cmd, java-11

Estoy comenzando un curso de java y me tocaba hacer mi primer programa HolaMundo.
Instale el JDK 12 y he establecido la ruta `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin` y luego me tocaba compilar el programa con el siguiente comando:

```
javac HolaMundo.java
```

Como resultado se creo un archivo `HolaMundo.class` ahora para ejecutar el programa intentado con el siguiente comando:

```
java HolaMundo
```

y me sale este error:

```
C:\Users\Fabricio\Desktop\JavaSE> java HolaMundo
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HolaMundo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Tiene toda la pinta de que tienes un compilador y un intérprete instalados simultáneamente y tu compilador de java (JDK) y tu intérprete (JRE) son de distintas versiones, y que tienes en el path, en primer lugar, el intérprete, antes del compilador.

Comprueba si tienes un JRE y JDK instalados simultáneamente en tu máquina y que ambos son de la misma versión.

En windows es relativamente sencillo, yendo a la ventana de programas instalados, lo verás.

En linux también es realtivamente sencillo, también, tendrás que buscarlos como ha indicado gustavovelascoh.

Un saludo.

Comment: Efectivamente el  JRE era de versión 8 y JDK de 12 eran de diferentes versiones. Des-instale el JRE8 y solo la deje con la JDK 12 ahi volvi a correr el programa y me funciono.

Comment: Una de las cosas que me han ocurrido mientras preparaba el plugin Pro*C para Eclipse era, precisamente, esto que te ha pasado a ti. Por eso sabía exactamente el procedimiento y qué te ocurría.

Comment: No necesitas desinstalar el JRE, basta con asegurarte de que ejecutas el "java" adecuado (por ejemplo, por línea de comandos, pones la ruta completa a "java.exe". O modificas el valor de la variable de entorno "PATH"

Comment: Si tienes un JDK en el path y un JRE, y pones el JRE en segundo lugar, jamás se ejecutaría, por lo que, ¿para qué quieres el JRE si ya lo tienes dentro del JDK? Usan los mismos recursos, la misma cantidad de memoria y el JRE se vuelve innecesario al estar **dentro** del JDK. Si lo que quieres es "verlo" como un usuario, se entendería, pero no es necesario tener ambas, salvo que te guste tenerlo "para nada".

Answer (score 2):

Como te menciona el mensaje de error, al parecer el programa se ha compilado con una versión más reciente de java, que la version con la que intentas ejecutarlo. Puedes comprobar si `javac` y `java`, los comandos que usas hacen parte de la misma instalación.

Si estas usando Linux puedes usar el comando `whereis`:

```
$ whereis java
$ whereis javac
```

Si estás en Windows, puedes usar el comando `where`:

```
> where java
> where javac
```

Comment: Como hago eso ?

Comment: javac -version (quizás con --version)
java -version (igual que la anterior)

Comment: @FabricioArciniega, he editado la respuesta.